# Difficulty deploying second artifact with Maven

Tags: maven, jar

A mavenized version of an old project of mine creates two Jar files, one for command line and one for GUI use. As it currently stands, it deploys only the primary artifact to the local repository. The jars are created by having two executions for maven-jar-plugin, and both get created in the target directory. What happens is the GUI file overwrites the primary one, with the wrong name:

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/gmcgath/DevProjects/git/jhove/target/jhove-GUI-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/gmcgath/.m2/repository/edu/harvard/hul/ois/jhove/1.12.0-SNAPSHOT/jhove-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm trying to use the build-helper plugin to get the GUI jar deployed to the repository, using the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-artifacts</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <artifacts>
              <artifact>
                <file>${project.artifactId}-GUI-${project.version}</file>
                <type>jar</type>
                <classifier>gui</classifier>
              </artifact>
            </artifacts>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maven runs to completion without any errors, but doesn't copy the jar properly. The log tells me it's trying to copy the GUI jar from the project-level directory instead of the target to the correct destination. The GUI file is still overwriting the primary jar.

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/gmcgath/DevProjects/git/jhove/jhove-GUI-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT to /Users/gmcgath/.m2/repository/edu/harvard/hul/ois/jhove/1.12.0-SNAPSHOT/jhove-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT-gui.jar
```

(The "harvard" part is historical. Keeping this open-source project was part of my severance package. :)

So I'm doing something basically wrong. How can I fix this? Should I be using the assembly plugin instead, even though it looks more complicated?

**Update:** Partially fixed. The file element in the artifact needs to be

```
<file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-GUI-${project.version}.jar</file>
```

I'm still looking for the fix to get the primary artifact copied correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's my fix. The first part, as indicated above, was to get the directory and extension right in the build-helper artifact. It should have been

```
<file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-GUI-${project.version}.jar</file>
```

The other issue was in a part of the pom.xml that I didn't post. The two executions lacked a classifier element, and so looked like this:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <!-- console app - don't change id, will cause build problems -->
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>cmd</classifier>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>Jhove</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
    <id>gui-app-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>gui</classifier>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>JhoveView</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-GUI-${project.version}</finalName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Everything looks OK now.